# Bootstrap 4 Card Row?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm using the card-deck class in Bootstrap 4. I would like the h4 to line up to the right of the img-thumbnail class within the card.

```
<div class="card-deck">
                    <div class="card">
                        <img class="img-thumbnail" src="img/camera.svg" alt="IMG ALT TEXT">
                        <h4 class="card-title">Header</h4>
                        <div class="card-block">
                            <p class="card-text">More Text Here</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: you mean you want to align the heading to the right side ?

Comment: correct. I want the img-thumbnail aligned to the top-left and the h4 aligned to the top-right,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just give a `width` to the class `.img-thumbnail` because by default the img take `max-width:100%;` you have to define a `width` and `text-align:right;` to the class `.card-title` and wrap them in a div and give it

```
.card-heading {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```css
.card-heading {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.img-thumbnail {
  width: 50px;
}

.card-title {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="card-deck">
  <div class="card">
  <div class="card-heading">        <img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/30x30" alt="IMG ALT TEXT">
    <h4 class="card-title">Header</h4></div>
    <div class="card-block">
      <p class="card-text">More Text Here</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same issue. The h4 is showing up in the row below the img-thumbnail, not beside it. You can click the blue "Run Code" button to see yourself

Comment: its beside each other you can click again and check

Comment: That did it! Thanks!